# How to write true/false in capitalize in excel via c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

whenever i write true/false in excel via c#. it shows and convert it into uppercase "`FALSE/TRUE`" in excel.

what should i do to remain it's case sensitivity?
I've tried with single quote " ' ", it shows what we want but logically it holds the value of single quote as well. ex: " `'False` " in excel shows as `False` , but in data it shows `'False` .

Is there any property changes, custom settings or via c# code can do this for me?

I'm writing data via c# DataTable to Excel worksheet cells in this manner.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtToExport.Rows.Count; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < dtToExport.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
       workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = dtToExport.Rows[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's built-in Excel functionality. See if you can format the cells or add a rule in the auto-correct options (haven't tested it).

Comment: Excel will convert `True` or `False` to the Boolean (and display it as such), unless you either format the worksheet cell as text **before** writing `True` into that cell, or prepend `True` with a single-quote (a `PrefixCharacter`) indicating to treat the contents of the cell as Text.

Comment: How can i format the worksheet cells or entire column as text via c# code?